# Serialize microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.validation.validationresults type

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, enterprise-library

Is it possible to serialize a class inheriting from `microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.validation.validationresults`.

When I create the object of

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeOf(subclass of ValidationResults));
```

it gives following exception at runtime.

To be xml serializable types which inherit from ienumerable must have an implementation of `add(system.object)` at all levels of their inheritance hierarchy. `microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.validation.validationresults` does not implement `Add(System.Object)` method.

Why do I get this exception? Is there any workaround for this issue. So that I can serialize the ValidationResults?

Comment: 1) Do you need to deserialize it later?  2) What does your subclass of `ValidationResults` look like?  If it has properties you want to serialize, `XmlSerializer` will not serialize them.  See [How/why does XmlSerializer treat a class differently when it implements IList<T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552724) and also [How to serialize an ICollection<T> that also has read/write properties to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34221481).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please see my comments below.1. I may have to de-serialize it later. coming to the second part of your question I have already mentioned that ValidationResults is class provided my Microsoft enterprise library. The complete name space is Microsoft.Practices.Enterpriselibrary.Validation.ValidationResults and don't have freedom to alter this library. Hence I can't just go ahead and implement Add method to satisfy the runtime request of XmlSerialzer. Hence trying to search a work around for this issue.

Comment: Can you show a code example of your subclass of [`ValidationResults`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.validation.validationresults.aspx)?  What data or properties does the subclass have that need to be serialized?  Also, can you make changes to the subclass?