# Serialize Keyedcollection which contains another keyedcollection

Tags: vb.net, nested, xmlserializer, keyedcollection

I recently started working with vb.net coming from vba.

For my planned application I wanted to create a KeyedCollection which stores another keyedcollection. The reason is I have a kind of database, where I want to be able to store for a varying number of "Parametersets", an now undefined number of "List_of_Parameters" where arrays of coefficients are stored.
My problem lies in serialization.
When I run the XMLSerialization only the deepestly nested elements are stored correctly. The elements one level above are just called "Array_of_node" and all the variables ignored except the keyedcollection.

I had expected that instead of  I would see the classname. Furthermore, I had expected to see something like this.

```
<Database>
   <Species>
     <Name>Parameterset 1</Name>
     <Node>...</Node>
     <Node>...</Node>
   </Species>
```

...

Any help would be really appreciated,
Best regards,
Johannes.

This is the xml-output I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Database xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ArrayOfNode>
    <Node>
      <Name>ListOfParameters_1</Name>
      <value>
        <double>1</double>
        <double>2</double>
        <double>3</double>
      </value>
    </Node>
    <Node>
      <Name>ListOfParameters_2</Name>
      <value>
        <double>5</double>
        <double>6</double>
      </value>
    </Node>
  </ArrayOfNode>
  <ArrayOfNode>
    <Node>
      <Name>ListOfParameters_1</Name>
      <value>
        <double>7</double>
        <double>8</double>
        <double>9</double>
      </value>
    </Node>
    <Node>
      <Name>ListOfParameters_2</Name>
      <value>
        <double>10</double>
        <double>11</double>
      </value>
    </Node>
  </ArrayOfNode>
</Database>
```

This is my Database:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports TestListofList
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports System.IO

<Serializable>
<XmlRootAttribute("Database")>
Public Class Database
    Inherits KeyedCollection(Of String, Species)

    Private myName As String
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return myName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            myName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Function GetKeyForItem(item As Species) As String
        Return item.Name
    End Function

    Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Sub New(ByVal name As String)
        Me.New()
        myName = name
    End Sub

    Public Sub SerializeToXML(ByVal filename As String)
        Dim locXMLWriter As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Database))
        Dim locXMLFile As New StreamWriter(filename)
        locXMLWriter.Serialize(locXMLFile, Me)
        locXMLFile.Flush()
        locXMLFile.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is the class which stores the List of "List_of_Coeffiencts" for the different parametersets:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports TestListofList
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

<Serializable>
Public Class Species
    Inherits KeyedCollection(Of String, Node)

    Public myName As String


    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return myName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            myName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Function GetKeyForItem(item As Node) As String
        Return item.Name
    End Function

    Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub
    Sub New(ByVal Name As String)
        Me.New()
        myName = Name
    End Sub
End Class
```

And this is the final "List of coefficients"

```
Public Class Node
    Private myName As String
    Private myvalue As Double()
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return myName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            myName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property value() As Double()
        Get
            Return myvalue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double())
            myvalue = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Sub New()

    End Sub

    Sub New(ByVal Name As String, value() As Double)
        myName = Name
        myvalue = value
    End Sub
End Class
```

And this my sample main program:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim dot As Node
        Dim molecule As Species
        Dim data As New Database

        molecule = New Species("Parameterset1")

        data.Add(molecule)
        dot = New Node("ListOfParameters_1", New Double() {1, 2, 3})
        data.Item("Parameterset1").Add(dot)
        dot = New Node("ListOfParameters_2", New Double() {5, 6})
        data.Item("Parameterset1").Add(dot)

        molecule = New Species("Parameterset2")
        data.Add(molecule)
        dot = New Node("ListOfParameters_1", New Double() {7, 8, 9})
        data.Item("Parameterset2").Add(dot)
        dot = New Node("ListOfParameters_2", New Double() {10, 11})
        data.Item("Parameterset2").Add(dot)




        data.SerializeToXML("C:\test.xml")
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Your problem is that you are trying to serialize properties of a collection.  `XmlSerializer` does not support this.  From [Serializing a Class that Implements the ICollection Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): **Any public properties or fields added to the class will not be serialized.**.  See [How/why does XmlSerializer treat a class differently when it implements IList<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552724)

Comment: See also [When a class is inherited from List<>, XmlSerializer doesn't serialize other attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069099/when-a-class-is-inherited-from-list-xmlserializer-doesnt-serialize-other-att).  For a workaround, see for instance [How to serialize an ICollection<T> that also has read/write properties to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34221481/how-to-serialize-an-icollectiont-that-also-has-read-write-properties-to-xml)

Comment: Thank you for your effort and explanation. I was not aware of that. I will try the datacontractserializer mentioned in one of your links and see I can get  results, which suit my problem. If so, I will post.

Comment: @Johannes, we hope that your issue has been resolved. May I suggest some further reading http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work... regards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.... (New code and classes)

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim Database1 As New List(Of Species)

    Dim Species1 As New Species
    Species1.Name = "SpeciesName1"
    Dim Parameterset1 As New Parameterset
    Parameterset1.Name = "Parameterset1"
    Parameterset1.Node.Add("1")
    Parameterset1.Node.Add("2")
    Parameterset1.Node.Add("3")
    Species1.Parameterset.Add(Parameterset1)

    Database1.Add(Species1)

    Dim Species2 As New Species
    Species2.Name = "SpeciesName2"
    Dim Parameterset2 As New Parameterset
    Parameterset2.Name = "Parameterset1"
    Parameterset2.Node.Add("1")
    Parameterset2.Node.Add("2")
    Species2.Parameterset.Add(Parameterset2)

    Database1.Add(Species2)

    ' to Serialize the object to test.xml
    Serialize(Database1)

    ' and to Deserialize from test.xml
    Dim Database2 As New List(Of Species)(Deserialize())
End Sub

Private Sub Serialize(SpeciesList As List(Of Species))

    ' Use a file stream here. 
    Using fs As New StreamWriter("test.xml")
        ' Construct a XmlSerializer and use it  
        ' to serialize the data to the stream. 
        Dim SerializerObj As New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of Species)))

        Try
            ' Serialize EmployeeList to the file stream
            SerializerObj.Serialize(fs, SpeciesList)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Failed to serialize. Reason: {0}", ex.Message))
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub

Private Function Deserialize() As List(Of Species)
    Dim EmployeeList2 = New List(Of Species)()

    ' Create a new file stream for reading the XML file
    Using fs = New StreamReader("test.xml")
        ' Construct a XmlSerializer and use it  
        ' to serialize the data from the stream. 
        Dim SerializerObj = New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of Species)))

        Try
            ' Deserialize the hashtable from the file
            EmployeeList2 = DirectCast(SerializerObj.Deserialize(fs), List(Of Species))
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Failed to serialize. Reason: {0}", ex.Message))
        End Try
    End Using
    ' return the Deserialized data.
    Return EmployeeList2
End Function

End Module

<XmlRoot(ElementName:="Parameterset")>
Public Class Parameterset
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="Name")>
    Public Property Name As String

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="Node")>
    Public Property Node As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
End Class

<XmlRoot(ElementName:="Species")>
Public Class Species

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="Name")>
    Public Property Name As String

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="Parameterset")>
    Public Property Parameterset As List(Of Parameterset) = New List(Of Parameterset)
End Class

<XmlRoot(ElementName:="Database")>
Public Class Database

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="Species")>
    Public Property Species As List(Of Species) = New List(Of Species)
End Class
```

The XML should look like this now.....

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ArrayOfSpecies xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <Species>
        <Name>SpeciesName1</Name>
        <Parameterset>
          <Name>Parameterset1</Name>
          <Node>1</Node>
          <Node>2</Node>
          <Node>3</Node>
        </Parameterset>
      </Species>
      <Species>
        <Name>SpeciesName2</Name>
        <Parameterset>
          <Name>Parameterset1</Name>
          <Node>1</Node>
          <Node>2</Node>
        </Parameterset>
      </Species>
    </ArrayOfSpecies>
```

Comment: Do you think it is possible to change the data structure to something like this?

Comment: <Array of Species> <Species> <Name>SpeciesName</Name><Parameterset><Name>Parameterset1</Name><Node>Node1</Node><Node>Node2</Node></Parameteset></Species><Species>....</Species></ArrayofSpecies>